# Rails 4.2 ActiveAdmin get admins email addr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

This query always returns `[nil]`

```
AdminUser.all.collect{|a|a.email}
```

However these two queries just work fine.

```
AdminUser.all
AdminUser.all.collect{|a| a.current_sign_in_ip}
```

Why can't i get the email addresses?

**Update**

The email field itself is not nil .It is present in the `AdminUser.all` call and also this call retuns the correct email.

```
>>au=AdminUser.find(1)
>>au[:email] 
=>my@email.addr
```

**Solution to the original problem**

Through another [question/problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261724/rails-4-2-activeadmin-1-0-0-pre2-cannot-create-a-adminuser-due-to-duplicate-key) i figured out i added `attr_accessor` on my `:email` field in my `model/admin_user.rb` i removed it and now also the 
      AdminUser.all.collect{|a|a.email}

query works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in first query:

```
AdminUsers.all.collect{|a|a.email} # should be AdminUser
```

The better way is to use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) for such queries:

```
AdminUser.pluck(:email)
```

Comment: Oh yeah thanks the typo was actually only here. But the second statement  works anyways ;) Thanks for the method!